# Mockito throws error with Kotlin when verifying with argument matchers or captors

Tags: kotlin, mockito

When using Mockito with Kotlin, if I try to verify Mock calls, it work fine like (this is in a Spring test):

```
 @MockBean
 lateinit var fragmentProcessor: FragmentProcessor

 verify(fragmentProcessor, timeout(20000)).processFragment(expectedFragment)
```

that gives the expected behaviour... but just doing something like:

```
 verify(fragmentProcessor, timeout(20000)).processFragment(Mockito.eq(expectedFragment))
```

will give the following error:

```
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at uk.co.argos.productapi.services.kafka.KafkaConsumerServiceTest.testFragmentProcessorReceivesMessages(KafkaConsumerServiceTest.kt:47)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

the same happens with ArgumentCaptor or other matchers

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you call `fragmentProcessor.processFragment(expectedFragment)` somewhere in your code before `verify` times out?

Error message says that you don't, so `verify` throws an exception (as it should do).

In this line:

```
verify(fragmentProcessor, timeout(20000)).processFragment(expectedFragment)
```

You don't use `verify` correctly (you have to use `Mockito.eq`): it doesn't verify anything so doesn't throw, but it doesn't mean that it works as you suppose.

Comment: If I don't use the eq it passes green. The problem arises if I use the eq

Comment: It passes green because without eq it does not verify anything. If you use the eq, it fails, because it should fail, because you don't invoke expected method in your code.